# Lparallel Package Switching in Threads

Tags: multithreading, package, common-lisp

Using the Lparallel library for Common Lisp, you can start a parallel thread running by calling `(submit-task channel function)`. This executes the given function in a new parallel thread. However, the function always seems to run in the :cl-user package, as opposed to the package in which it is defined. I’m just wondering why Lparallel was designed this way. You can override by including `(in-package :my-package)` in the function, but is there some advantage to this predictability?

```
#-:lparallel
  (ql:quickload :lparallel)

(defpackage :test (:use :cl :lparallel))

(in-package :test)

(defun main ()
  (setf lparallel:*kernel* (lparallel:make-kernel 1))
  (print *package*)
  (let ((c (make-channel)))
    (submit-task c (lambda () (print *package*))))
  (lparallel:end-kernel))
```

gives:

```
* (load "d:\\test.lisp")
To load "lparallel":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    lparallel
; Loading "lparallel"

T
* (in-package :test)
#<PACKAGE "TEST">
* (main)

#<PACKAGE "TEST">
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
(#<SB-THREAD:THREAD "lparallel kernel shutdown manager" FINISHED values: NIL {1005873953}>
 #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "lparallel" FINISHED values: NIL {10058735F3}>)
```

Comment: how should a function 'know' in which package it was defined? functions and packages are completely unrelated. Remember, a package is a namespace for symbols.

Comment: `*PACKAGE*` is a special variable, so what the [documentation](https://lparallel.org/kernel/) says about dynamic bindings applies to it as well.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig, Yes, I was confusing the function and its name.

Comment: @jkiiski, So the value of `*package*` in the first `(print *package*)` refers to the value of its dynamic rebinding following `(in-package :test)`. The second `(print *package*)` refers to the original global value in :cl-user, because it is in a thread. (If it were in an ordinary function instead, it would still refer to the dynamic rebinding.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behaviour for dynamic variables is that only a binding in the *global environment* (i. e. not a dynamic re-binding) is shared between threads.

The value of `*package*` is mostly irrelevant at runtime, except when `read`ing (which is unusual at runtime, and you'd explicitly bind `*package*` for that anyway).  There is thus no reason to deviate from the standard behaviour described above.

There is also no connection between code (e. g. a function) and the package that was the value of `*package*` when it was read, compiled, or loaded.  The only effect of `*package*` is the default package when interning, finding, or printing symbols.

Comment: There are a bunch of runtime differences depending to the package variable: reading, interning of symbols, find-symbol and printing of symbols.

Comment: OK, thanks. Got mixed up about packages once again. Will it ever end.